# Mutate across columns case_when to make a new "Flag" column

Tags: r, dplyr, case

I have a huge dataset (df) containing numerous columns listing information on number of people on treatment x (e.g. Treat_1) per country (ISO3) and per year (Year).

I need to generate a new column that is called "Flag_Treat_X" (where X stands for the original column name e.g Treat_1). In this column I need to record any treatment decline compared to the previous year as "down", increases as "up" and NA where there is missing data. All columns containing treatment information have "_" in their names, but the actual df uses complex names like HIV_treatment, etc instead of a combination of string and numbers as used here. I know several ways to do it column by column (see below) but the dataset is so huge and the variable names changes often that I need an automated way of doing this.

Here is the code for a simplified example:

```
ISO3 <- c("AFG", "AFG","AFG", "BEN", "BEN","BEN", "GIN", "GIN", "GIN", "ZWE", "ZWE", "ZWE")
Year <- c(2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022)
Treat_1 <- c(100, 110, 120, 300, 330, 360, 200, 220, 100, 300, NA, 320)

df = data.frame(ISO3, Year, Treat_1)
```

Here is an example of how I could do it column by column by hand

```
df_poutcome %>%
   group_by(ISO3) %>%
   mutate(Target_art_n_pf = case_when(Treat_1<lag(Treat_1) ~ "down",
                                      Treat_1>lag(Treat_1) ~ "up", 
                                      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)))
```

Here is an example that "nearly" works using a loop (not very elegant)

```
for (i in grep("_", names(temp), value=TRUE)){
 
  varname = ((gsub(" ", "", paste("Flag_",i))))
  temp = temp %>%
       group_by(ISO3) %>%
       mutate(!!varname:= case_when(i<lag(i) ~ "down",
                                   i>lag(i) ~ "up"))

}
```

The error is that I only get NA values for all the new "Flag_[...]" variables and the code

```
TRUE ~ as.character(NA)
```

does not run in the case_when code so I have to remove it.

The desired outcome should look as follows:

| ISO3 | Year | Treat_1 | Flag_Treat_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFG | 2020 | 100 | NA |
| AFG | 2021 | 110 | up |
| AFG | 2022 | 120 | up |
| BEN | 2020 | 300 | NA |
| BEN | 2021 | 330 | up |
| BEN | 2022 | 360 | up |
| GIN | 2020 | 200 | NA |
| GIN | 2021 | 220 | up |
| GIN | 2022 | 100 | down |
| ZWE | 2020 | 300 | NA |
| ZWE | 2021 | NA | NA |
| ZWE | 2022 | 320 | NA |

Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: I would recommend deleting your "bonus"--keep your question focused on one goal. Combining two questions into one discourages people from answering if they can only answer. Ask your "bonus" question as its own question once this one is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much to everyone for the quick responses. I ended up using a blend of the responses to make it run on my side. Code below.

```
df %>%
  group_by(ISO3) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("_"),
                ~case_when(
                  .x < lag(.x) ~ "down",
                  .x > lag(.x) ~ "up", 
                  TRUE ~ as.character(NA)
                ),
                .names = "flag_{.col}"
  ))
```

I had to change the `\(x)` suggested by Gregor Thomas to the code suggested by jdobres `~case_when(       .x < lag(.x) ~ "down",       .x > lag(.x) ~ "up",        TRUE ~ as.character(NA)     )` as it was giving me an unexpected symbol

Answer (score 3):

You can use `across()` to apply a function across columns with a criteria (here, columns containing `"_"` in their names), and use the `.names` argument to name the resulting columns:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ISO3) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("_"),
    \(x) case_when(
      x < lag(x) ~ "down",
      x > lag(x) ~ "up", 
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)
    ),
    .names = "flag_{.col}"
  ))
# # A tibble: 12 × 4
# # Groups:   ISO3 [4]
#    ISO3   Year Treat_1 flag_Treat_1
#    <chr> <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>       
#  1 AFG    2020     100 NA          
#  2 AFG    2021     110 up          
#  3 AFG    2022     120 up          
#  4 BEN    2020     300 NA          
#  5 BEN    2021     330 up          
#  6 BEN    2022     360 up          
#  7 GIN    2020     200 NA          
#  8 GIN    2021     220 up          
#  9 GIN    2022     100 down        
# 10 ZWE    2020     300 NA          
# 11 ZWE    2021      NA NA          
# 12 ZWE    2022     320 NA
```

Comment: Rather than `\(x)`, I believe `~case_when(
      .x < lag(.x) ~ "down",
      .x > lag(.x) ~ "up", 
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)
    )` would work as well?

Comment: @jdobres Yes, you can use `function(x)` anywhere, or `\(x)` anywhere with R version 4.1.0 or greater, or `~` with `.x` in certain functions that support purrr-style lambdas, which `across()` does, so that will work here.

Comment: Now that base R has a short-hand lambda function syntax, I assume that the purrr-style lambdas will decline in use. `\(x)` is more efficient, more general, and probably safer.